# Writing a generic method for two completely different types

Tags: c#

I am currently adding additions to someone else's code and have come across a PdfBuilder class which is using the  PdfSharp dll. Up until this point the class has taken a type called `BoxRequest` in the constructor. like so:

```
    public PdfDocument GenerateAddressLabelPdf(int id)
    {
        var box = _unitOfWork.BoxRepository.GetById(id);
        var generator = new PdfBuilder(box);
        return generator.BuildPdfDocument();
    }
```

And the `PdfBuilder` class looks like this:

```
    public class PdfBuilder
    {
        private readonly BoxRequest _boxRequest;

        public PdfBuilder(BoxRequest boxRequest)
        {
            _boxRequest = boxRequest;
        }

        public PdfDocument BuildPdfDocument()
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

            PdfPage page = pdfDocument.AddPage();
            page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 40, XFontStyle.Regular);
            XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
            XRect rect = new XRect(0, (page.Height/4), page.Width, page.Height);
            gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.White, rect);
            tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Center;
            tf.DrawString(GetText(), font, XBrushes.Black, rect);          

            return pdfDocument;
        }

        private string GetText()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(_boxRequest.Name);
            sb.AppendLine(_boxRequest.Department);
            sb.AppendLine(_boxRequest.Location.LocationName);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

So as you can see the properties used in `GetText` are taken from the `FileRequest` type.

I now need to use this class again, this time for a new type called `FileRequest`, As soon as I made the call to this class and saw it only takes a `BoxRequest` I thought this could be a good thing to make generic.

So far I have changed the class like so:

```
    public class PdfBuilder<T>
    {
        private readonly T _pdfType;

        public PdfBuilder(T t)
        {
            _pdfType = t;
        }

        //additional class stuff
     }
```

But now I am a little confused as to how I should make the `GetText` method generic, as I need to render certain lines for each and every type.

At this point I think I could pass the type to `GetText` and then check the type and append different lines based on type, but it seems like its no longer really generic?

Comment: It's unlikely you need generics. You either need to extract interface from BoxRequest and FileRequest or\and create separate PdfBuilder classes for them (inheriting from one of course).

Comment: Perhaps you can make T an interface implemented by all your concrete objects?

Comment: if all thats different is `GetText` how about overriding the `BoxRequest` and the other classes `ToString`method and not caring about the type at all? You could the replace `GetText()` with sth. `input.ToString()` otherwise, extract `GetText()` to an interface and let both of cour classes implement that in a proper way

Comment: Does `FileRequest` object have `Name`, `Departament` and `Location.LocationName` properties, just as `BoxRequest`? That is: is the *way to print* exactly the same or is it different?

Comment: Yet another way is to pass function which builds text to constructor: public PdfBuilder(Func<string> textBuilder). After all your PdfBuilder does not care about specific requets (at least in code shown). All what it cares about is to provide some text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think generics are the best way of handling this issue...

If all thats different is `GetText` the simplest (not best) way to resolve this would be overriding the BoxRequest and the other classes `ToString()` method and not caring about the type at all.

```
public class BoxRequest
{
    // ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(this.Name);
        sb.AppendLine(this.Department);
        sb.AppendLine(this.Location.LocationName);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class PdfBuilder
{
    private readonly object request;

    public PdfBuilder(object request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public PdfDocument BuildPdfDocument()
    {
        // ...

        tf.DrawString(request.ToString(), font, XBrushes.Black, rect);          

        // ...
    }

}
```

This way, you could use the class to PDF any object. If this is to generic for you (for me it is), you could extract an interface for `ToString()`/`GetText()` and let your `PdfBuilder` consume that (which would be way cleaner IMO).

```
public interface IPdfConvertible
{
    public string GetText()
}

// same for FileRequest...
public class BoxRequest : IPdfConvertible
{
    // ...

    public string GetText()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(this.Name);
        sb.AppendLine(this.Department);
        sb.AppendLine(this.Location.LocationName);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class PdfBuilder
{
    private readonly IPdfConvertible request;

    public PdfBuilder(IPdfConvertible request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public PdfDocument BuildPdfDocument()
    {
        // ...

        tf.DrawString(request.GetText(), font, XBrushes.Black, rect);          

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am personally in favor of declaring a new `IPdfPrintable` interface with `GetText()` method so that: 1) `PdfBuilder` requires an object of that interface (and not any object); 2) the well known meaning of `ToString()` is unchanged.